# Universal username/password authentication in express.js or react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Setting up user authentication can be easily achieved in apache by setting up .htaccess and .htpasswd However I am developing an new web application and I am using express.js or react.js to create a web server. I searched user authentication online but they are long projects for email style logins like [here](https://vladimirponomarev.com/blog/authentication-in-react-apps-creating-components). All I need is a single universal username and password. When a user browse to my website a pop appear for the username and password. (Same like .htaccess style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understandings you need http server authentication in nodejs.

I know one npm module. [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-auth)

And it's pretty easy to setup also. 
Basic example

```
// Authentication module. 
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd"
});

// Creating new HTTP server. 
http.createServer(basic, (req, res) => {
    res.end(`Welcome to private area - ${req.user}!`);
}).listen(1337);
```

Comment: I will implement it on Tuesday but this seems the right answer and thank you for the link. The .htpasswd format will be same ? like it will have a single line with username:password in this case Simon:password

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested to do in ES2016 then follow the following code. Set the babel etc to make it work.

```
import express from 'express';
import auth from 'http-auth';
// Configure basic auth
const basic = auth.basic({ 
realm: 'SUPER SECRET STUFF'
}, (username, password, callback) => { 
callback(username == 'admin' && password == 'password'); 
});
// Set up express app
const app = express();
// Create middleware that can be used to protect routes with basic auth
const authMiddleware = auth.connect(basic);
// Protected route
app.get('/', authMiddleware, (request, response) => { 
response.send('you made it!'); 
});
app.listen(3000);
```